# I want to find friend relationship in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Friend of a friend in PHP/MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977904/friend-of-a-friend-in-php-mysql)

i use mysql and PHP. i have 2 tables :

table user:

```
id (int)
name (varchar)
```

table contain user's friend:

```
user_id (int)
friend_id (int)
```

the question is : if i have 2 user id, let's say id = 101 and id =1000 how can i know the relationship between these 2 id ? is id 101 is friend of friend of friend from id 1000 or what ?

in facebook/ friendster, how come they can generate

Comment: Possible answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977904/friend-of-a-friend-in-php-mysql]

Comment: enough repeats on this question to indicate an assignment somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
*
FROM user
INNER JOIN friends ON friends.user_id = user.id
WHERE 
user.id = '101' AND friends.friend_id = 1000
```

Comment: there is a more complicate recursion going on here.  this should involve a connect by query (Oracle) or some other hierarchic result set.

Comment: It is not possible in MySQL (like Oracle). Actually you can recursively check relationship using function.

Comment: Thx alot eriks Daliba,so, basically it is imposibble in MySQL ? but i heard facebook use mySQl. how can they do it ?

Comment: Well, you can create mysql function which will recursively check your friends, than friends of your friends etc returning true or false. This is not efficient way (usage of function) with large data set. Does facebook provide checking >2 levels? ie friends of your friend friends?

Answer (score 0):

NOT an answer, but how i would do it. Two ideas:

1. Make different queries using #ofJoins=how far is relationship
2. Build decision tree in php and to scan it

Comment: thx ivil, what do you mean by decision tree in php ?

Comment: I mean just build it up to selected depth...:  Node1: me, Node1.1: myFriend1, Node1.2: myFriend2, Node1.2.1:myFriend2'sFriend1    and so on.